# Make Me a Sandwich

Tags: popularity-contest

[image: XKCD: Sandwich]

Challenge: Write a makefile, which would lead to this behavior:

```
% make me a sandwich
What? Make it yourself
% sudo make me a sandwich
Okay
```

Rules:

1. Should work on a Linux machine, where the user isn't root but allowed to use `sudo`.
2. Must not say `Okay` to any shorter make command (e.g. `sudo make sandwich`).
3. The second command should work because of `sudo`, not because it's the second invocation.

Guidelines:

1. Keep it short (after all, it's a Code Golf site).
2. It would be nice if it would actually make a sandwich.
3. Try to cleverly hide why `sudo` makes a difference.

The winner will be decided by votes.

Comment: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?23273

Comment: @ardnew, unfortunately, I specifically requested to write a makefile, which, I think, invalidates solutions based on patching `make`.

Comment: totally agree, @ugoren. didnt mean for that comment to dismiss the challenge or suggest a solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I'll bite. This doesn't necessarily adhere to guideline #3, but it does a fair job on the other two guidelines. It also cleans up after itself, as any good sandwich-maker should.

```
.SILENT:

%:%.c
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ && rm -f $^

default:
        echo 'The makings for a sandwich are here.'

a.c:
        echo '#include <stdio.h>' > a.c
        echo 'int main() {' >> a.c
        echo '  char *txt[] = { "What? Make it yourself.", "Okay." };' >> a.c
        echo '  int n = 0;' >> a.c
        echo '  while (getchar() != EOF) n ^= 1;' >> a.c
        echo '  puts(txt[n]); return 0; }' >> a.c

me.c:
        echo '#include <stdio.h>' > me.c
        echo '#include <unistd.h>' >> me.c
        echo 'int main() {' >> me.c
        echo '  char *txt[] = { "/dev/null", "sandwich" };' >> me.c
        echo '  puts(txt[!getuid()]); return 0; }' >> me.c

sandwich:
        ./me | ./a | tee `./me`
        rm -f me a

clean:
        rm -f sandwich
```

(Less buggy, and hopefully a bit less boring, than my initial submission.)

Comment: Looks like it violates rule #2 - `sudo make me sandwich`.

Comment: `&& test -e ./a`

Comment: Argh, you're right. This version should do a better job of observing the rules.

Comment: you certainly have the most appropriate name, @breadbox

Answer (score 9):

A fairly compact solution that ignores guideline #2 (127 characters, including some unnecessary whitespace). I follow [breadbox's practice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12166) of cleaning up after myself. Don't put any other file in the same directory as the makefile! Also, note that the makefile must be called `Makefile`, other names will not work.

```
me: ; echo echo Okay >$@
a: ; chmod u=x me
sandwich: ; ./me 2>/dev/null || echo 'What? Make it yourself'; rm -f [!M]*
.SILENT:
```

Usage:

```
$ make me a sandwich
What? Make it yourself
$ sudo make me a sandwich
Okay
$ sudo make me sandwich  
What? Make it yourself
$ sudo make a sandwich
chmod: cannot access `me': No such file or directory
make: *** [a] Error 1
$ sudo make sandwich  
What? Make it yourself
```

I like the way this one deals with guideline #3. Just one press of <kbd>Shift</kbd> makes the difference.

Answer (score 4):

Not mine, and not a true solution as it violates rule #2, but it has a very interesting story that led me here:

```
# With apologies to XKCD #149
me:
    @:
a:
    @:
sandwich:
    @[ "$$(id -u)" -eq 0 ] && { echo "Okay"; touch sandwich; } || echo "What? Make it yourself!"
```

So, where this came from?

I was just messing with the cloud-init script `/boot/user-data` in Ubuntu 22.04 Server image for Raspberry Pi, when I came into this example snippet:

```
## Write arbitrary files to the file-system (including binaries!)
#write_files:
#- path: /etc/default/console-setup
#  content: |
#    # Consult the console-setup(5) manual page.
#    ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"
#    CHARMAP="UTF-8"
#    VIDEOMODE=
#    FONT="Lat15-Terminus18x10.psf.gz"
#    FONTFACE=
#    FONTSIZE=
#    CODESET="Lat15"
#  permissions: '0644'
#  owner: root:root
#- encoding: gzip
#  path: /root/Makefile
#  content: !!binary |
#    H4sICF2DTWIAA01ha2VmaWxlAFNWCM8syVBILMjPyU/PTC1WKMlXiPB2dlFQNjSx5MpNteLi
#    dLDiSoRQxYl5KeWZyRkgXrSCkoqKRmaKgm6pppKCbmqhgoFCrIKamkK1QmpyRr6Ckn92YqWS
#    NdC80uQMBZhOa4VahZoaqIrwjMQSewXfxOxUhcwShcr80qLi1Jw0RSUuAIYfEJmVAAAA
#  owner: root:root
#  permissions: '0644'
```

That binary blob caught my eye... was that an executable? A binary Makefile? It made no sense. Assuming this was plain text with base64 encoding, I tried in a terminal:

```
$ txt='H4sICF2DTWIAA01ha2VmaWxlAFNWCM8syVBILMjPyU/PTC1WKMlXiPB2dlFQNjSx5MpNteLi
> dLDiSoRQxYl5KeWZyRkgXrSCkoqKRmaKgm6pppKCbmqhgoFCrIKamkK1QmpyRr6Ckn92YqWS
> NdC80uQMBZhOa4VahZoaqIrwjMQSewXfxOxUhcwShcr80qLi1Jw0RSUuAIYfEJmVAAAA'
$ printf "$txt" | base64 -d
]�MbMakefileS�,�PH,���O�L-V(�W��vvQP64���M���t��J�Pŉy)��� ^�����Ff��n����nj���B����B�BjrF���vb��5м��
                                                                                                      �Nk�Z�������{���T�����Ң�Ԝ4E%.���
```

Ouch, a true binary indeed! What the hell..

Oh, wait... `encoding: gzip`. Hummm...

```
$ printf "$txt" | base64 -d | gunzip
```

Ta-da! The `Makefile` above appears!

What a convoluted Easter Egg from... well, I have no idea! And, what was that all about?

So I read the comic, experimented a bit with that Makefile, finally understood the joke, then googled for "make me a sandwich", and finally arrived here!

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This is certainly an unconventional way to arrive at a solution :p

Answer (score 3):

This solution doesn't adhere to guideline #2 — or does being vaguely sandwich-shaped count? I went on a kind of palindrome theme at the beginning, but I could only find so many ways to make lines symmetric without resorting to lame `real code # ecod laer`. I didn't take guideline #1 very seriously, aesthetics comes first.

Remember that it's a makefile; the 3 successive lines beginning with `if`, `rm` and `echo` begin with a tab. The other indented lines begin with spaces.

```
me : mr ; env | grep -q DO_US || rm -- mr || SU_OD q- perg | vne ; rm : em
                            .SILENT:##:TNELIS.
                              . = a.  .a = .
$(.:.=):;:>$@
sandwich:
    if expr>/dev/null $$(id -u); then echo 'What? Make it yourself'; fi
    rm f- a me mr 2>/dev/null
    echo Okay
mr : ; true : ; touch me : em f- mr || rm -f me : em hcuot ; : eurt ; : rm
```

Usage (the commands can be issued in any order):

```
$ sudo make me a sandwich     
Okay
$ sudo make me sandwich  
make: *** [sandwich] Error 1
$ sudo make a sandwich 
make: *** [sandwich] Error 1
$ sudo make sandwich  
make: *** [sandwich] Error 1
$ make me a sandwich
What? Make it yourself
make: *** [sandwich] Error 1
```

As for guideline #3, this isn't cleverly hidden, just slightly weirdly. Some hints:

> There are two different tests: one search for `SUDO_USER`, and one test of whether `id -u` prints 0. Do you see why `What?` is *not* printed for root? Do you see how the lack of `SUDO_USER` causes `Okay` not to be printed?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a first go using a different and simpler technique:

```
.SILENT:

reset_command:
    @rm -f command

me a sandwich: reset_command
    @echo $@ >> command
    -@make `cat command | tr "\n" "_"` 2>/dev/null

me_a_sandwich_: reset_command
    @if [ `whoami` == "root" ]; then echo "Okay"; else echo "What? Make it yourself."; fi
```

I'm pretty sure there is more that I can do with this - get it to respond to other input commands for instance. I'll have to work on the root switch obfuscation and the actual sandwich making.